# cannot import wordnet from python code

Tags: python-2.7

I want to access wordnet from my python code. I am using the following code for this purpose:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
word=wn.synsets('dog')
print word
```

I get no error but no output also.The same code on python interpreter gives the correct output. can anyone suggest some method to resolve this problem.